# Ansible ssh connection

Tags: ssh, ansible

I know there are a few about this but so far nothing seems to work for me. 
So I am trying to learn to use Ansible and I got stuck at this ssh connection issue. I think I did everything right however I would appreciate if someone would help out. Let me post the files I have configures and the result I have.

```
### ansible.cfg ###
    [defaults]
    inventory = ./Playbooks/hosts
    remote_user = ansible
    private_key_file = .ssh/id_key.pub

### Playbooks/hosts ###
    [server]
    ubu1 ansible_ssh_host=192.16.20.69 ansible_ssh_pass=qwerty ansible_ssh_user=ansible

### Command executed ###
    sudo ansible -m ping -vvvv ubu1

 ### The result I get ###
Using /home/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
    Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
    <192.16.20.69> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
    <192.16.20.69> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile=".ssh/id_key.pub"' -o User=ansible -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.16.20.69 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470766758.25-258256142287087 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1470766758.25-258256142287087="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470766758.25-258256142287087 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''

    ubu1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
        "unreachable": true
    }
```

Unfortunalty I am unable to continue learning Ansible until I get this solved. One of the things I am wondering if the ssh-agent is not interfering with Ansible and if so and I must admit I have no clue on what to next.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks 
Perry

Comment: Anything interesting in `/var/log/auth.log` on `ubu1`?

Comment: Hi have no entry coming from the playbook in there however if I connect using regular ssh then yes I get an entry.

Comment: If you run the ssh command there (`ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile=".ssh/id_key.pub"' -o User=ansible -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.16.20.69`) does it work?  If not, what error does it give you?  Have you tried making `private_key_file` an absolute path, rather than a relative one?

Comment: Try `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible -m ping -vvvv ubu1` and check the exact error message.

Comment: Ok I tried with two different user but I get the same errors. So I ran the first command and I notice this line [link] Control socket connect(/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.16.20.69-22-ansible): Permission denied [/link] and I realize that the folder .ansible/ as root permissions so I modified the permissions to ansible and now this is what I get - OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.16.20.69-22-ansible" does not exist
debug2: resolving "192.16.20.69" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.16.20.69 [192.16.20.69] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 192.16.20.69 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.16.20.69 port 22: Connection timed out)

Comment: seems to be some routing/firewall problem. is the address 192.16.20.69 correct? not 192.168.20.69?

Comment: Ok i finally figure out whats going on.
First indead I mixed up the ipaddress with the one at home should ahd been 172.16.20.69.
I changed a few settings such has the private_key_file I removed .pub
In the host file I simplified by only having the ip address.
But the main this was that my server did not had Python installed.
I had installed the server with minimum ressources, I did not expect that Python had to be installed. Now everything is workin has expected. 
Thank you for everyone who help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from comments above:

> Try `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible -m ping -vvvv ubu1` and check the exact error message

Allowed to trace down problems with ip-addresses and python installation.